# Reuse containers with `docker-compose`

Tags: docker, docker-compose, supervisord

I've an app running on multiple Docker containers defined by `docker-compose`. Everything works fine from my user and the `docker-compose ps` output looks like:

```
       Name                Command           State     Ports
------------------------------------------------------------
myuser_app_1    /config/bootstrap.sh   Exit 137
myuser_data_1   sh                     Exit 0
myuser_db_1     /run.sh                Exit 143
```

Now I'm trying to run `docker-compose up` with `supervisord` (see relevant part of `supervisord.conf` below) and the issue is that the containers are now named `myapp_app_1`, `myapp_data_1` and `myapp_db_1`, that is they're created from scratch and all customizations on the former containers is lost.

I tried renaming the containers, but it gives an error saying that there's already a container with that name.

**Q:** Is there some way to force `docker-compose` reuse existing containers instead of creating new ones based in their respective images?

> supervisord.conf
>
> ```
> ...
> [program:myapp]
> command=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
>     -f /usr/local/app/docker-compose.yml up
> redirect_stderr=true
> stdout_logfile=/var/log/myapp_container.log
> stopasgroup=true
> user=myuser
> ```

Comment: If you only need one container per app then you can use `container_name: app` in your docker-compose.yml file

Comment: `docker-compose` by default uses the folder name of the yml file as the project name, and prefix that name to all container names. You can specify the project name using `docker-compose -p custom_name`. I am not sure if this will force reuse existing containers with the same names though. Try test this first on unimportant containers first if you have important data you don't want to overwrite.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compose [will always reuse containers as long as their config hasn't changed](https://docs.docker.com/compose/#only-recreate-containers-that-have-changed).

If you have any state in a container, you need to put that state into a volume. Containers should be ephemeral, you should be able to destroy them and recreate them at any time without losing anything.

If you need to initialize something I would do it in the Dockerfile, so that it's preserved in the image.

Comment: I finally managed to reuse the data volumes by specifying `volumes_from` in `docker-compose.yml`. Thanks for the hints.