# Rename a project by keeping containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I decided to change the project name of a docker composition:

```sh
$ docker-compose -p old_name up -d # Before
Starting old_name_web_1
$ docker-compose -p new_name up -d # After
Creating new_name_web_1
```

But I don't wanted to delete my containers, so I renamed them:

```sh
$ docker rename old_name_web_1 new_name_web_1
...
```

I thought docker-compose was based on container names, but it does not seem to be the case:

```sh
$ docker-compose -p new_name up -d
```

> ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: Conflict. The name "/new_name_web_1" is already in use by container 4930deaabb[...]. You have to remove (or rename) that container to be able to reuse that name.
>   ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.

How can I relink my old containers to the new composition ?

Comment: Downvoted since the whole concept of docker has been underminded here. In a docker world, even slightly caring about container being removed / recreating is wrong. Container should be seen and treated similar to tmp files - you can and want to recreate them.

Comment: Not sure it deserves a downvote since the question is clear to me, but I understand what you are saying. It would deserve an answer though that would help others like me who maybe don't have the correct way of thinking.

Comment: any answer to this question is completely abusing the concept in terms, that it actual harms you hugely in the long term doing that. Since your question is not on "how to do docker in general", but far more specific, i cannot give an answer without just not answering a total different question / not the initial question. You should really get down the bottom, why you need that here, if you need that here - and what has you forced in that situation in general. A normal manager like swarm/kubernetes/rancher does delete container anytime for "restart" the stack.Container=not persistent

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using one of the newer versions of docker compose which tracks containers by labels assigned to them rather than by their names. That is why renaming the container didn't work.

#### Updating labels

You can check container's labels through the `docker inspect` command.

```
$ docker inspect --format='{{json .Config.Labels }}' container_name
```

The project name is the value of the 'com.docker.compose.project' label.

Moving an existing container to a new project is as easy as changing the value of that label. However it is not yet supported by Docker CLI. There is [an open issue requesting that feature](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/21721).

#### Workaround

It still can be achieved by directly editing the configuration file of that particular container. There you will find labels currently assigned to that container.

```
$ nano /var/lib/docker/containers/$container_id/config.v2.json
```

Assign the new project name to the 'com.docker.compose.project' label and save the file. Next you have to restart the daemon. Otherwise the changes will not be visible to docker.

```
$ systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: It seems that this workaround doesn't work (as of v19.03.1)... the `config.v2.json` is re-written to it's original value... perhaps a stop / edit / start would work better.

Answer (score 1):

While it is true [`docker-compose` reuse existing containers](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/#only-recreate-containers-that-have-changed), [this comment mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756168/reuse-containers-with-docker-compose#comment61096108_36756168):

> `docker-compose` by default uses the folder name of the yml file as the project name, and prefix that name to all container names.

This could explain why [`docker-compose up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/) did not pick up the new container name.

Comment: The directory name is the last fallback for project naming, I'm defining it explicitly with `-p` here (I also renamed the directory by the way)

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY -p? I didn't see a -p in your question.

Comment: Damned I've put `-f` instead of `-p` in the question (I'm also using the file override, that's why I confused them), let me update it.

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY OK ;) I don't have an immediate answer, though.