# How to keep node_modules inside container while using docker-compose and a non-root user?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm looking for a way to achieve these goals at the same time:

- using a **non-root user** inside the container
- keeping `node_modules` inside container (to not to "pollute" the working directory on the host)
- not using a `Dockerfile`

I'm not sure if these goals are considered "best practice". For example, keeping `node_modules` inside the container has its [disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756168/reuse-containers-with-docker-compose).

Currently my compose file is like this:

```
services:
  # ...

  node:
    image: "node:9"
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      # - NODE_ENV=production
      - NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
      - PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
    volumes:
      - ./proj/:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules # mark1
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"
    command: >
      bash -c "echo hello
      && ls -lh /home/node/app/ 
      && npm install
      && npm i -g babel-cli
      && npm i -g flow-bin
      && npm start"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```

but there's

> `"Error: EACCES: permission denied, access`
>   `'/home/node/app/node_modules'".`

If I comment out the `#mark1` line, the container runs, however `node_modules` will be written onto the host (since `./proj` is [mounted](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes))

I have read these two articles on the topic:

- https://blog.getjaco.com/jaco-labs-nodejs-docker-missing-manual/
- http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html

but neither meets my goal.

### Update:

I added a line of `ls -lh /home/node/app/` and found `node_modules` is owned by `root`. This could be the problem.

Comment: It's not same question. In that question, they use a root user.

Comment: Should the volume for your node modules not be `./proj/:/home/node/.......`? so it's relative to the docker data dir, instead of the absolute location?

Comment: Since no Dockerfile is used, I did that to feed the project files to the container.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using a `Dockerfile`. It's minimum. (I keep some commented out lines for anyone may find them useful.)

We need to change the owner of `node_modules` inside the container. <del>It seems the `node:9` image doesn't require this. So this is only for `node:9-alpine`.</del> (**update**: Sorry. I forgot to remove the built container with `docker system prune`. Both images need this. Here is [a discussion on  permissions/ownership of named volumes`](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3270))

```
FROM node:9-alpine

#ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
#ENV PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin

RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules
RUN chown -R node:node /home/node/app

#USER node

#WORKDIR /home/node/app

#RUN npm install --silent --progress=false ; \
#    npm i -g babel-cli --silent --progress=false ;\
#    npm i -g flow-bin --silent --progress=false
```

The `docker-compose.yml` ended up being like:

```
services:
  # ...
  node:
    # image: "node:9-alpine"
    build: ./proj
    user: "node"
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    environment:
      # - NODE_ENV=production
      - NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
      - PATH=$PATH:/home/node/.npm-global/bin
    volumes:
      - ./proj/:/home/node/app
      - /home/node/app/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3006:3001"
    command: >
      /bin/sh -c "echo hello
      && ls -lh /home/node/app/
      && npm install
      && npm i -g babel-cli
      && npm i -g flow-bin
      && npm start"
    depends_on:
      - redis
```